# SFDX CLI: What command should I run when I have both Local Add and Remote Add and Remote Changed in my Source: Status report

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, scratch-org

I've added a couple of `Apex` classes locally but also changed a `Profile` in the scratch org.

When I run:

```
sfdx force:source:status
```

I get a response with `Local Add` and `Remote Changed` and `Remote Add`

```
STATE           FULL NAME              TYPE       PROJECT PATH
──────────────  ─────────────────────  ─────────  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Local Add       AppInstallHandler      ApexClass  app\main\default\classes\AppInstallHandler.cls
Local Add       AppInstallHandler      ApexClass  app\main\default\classes\AppInstallHandler.cls-meta.xml
Local Add       AppInstallHandlerTest  ApexClass  app\main\default\classes\AppInstallHandlerTest.cls
Local Add       AppInstallHandlerTest  ApexClass  app\main\default\classes\AppInstallHandlerTest.cls-meta.xml
Remote Changed  Admin                  Profile    app\main\default\profiles\Admin.profile-meta.xml
Remote Add      MyConnectedApp         ConnectedApp
```

I want all the additions\changes.

Last time I had this situation, I did:

```
sfdx force:source:pull
```

And then the `Local Add` disappeared from my `source:status` report, but files still existed locally, but they were not in the remote scratch org!

What sequence of `SFDX` commands should I run to ensure, that all the changes are synced, so they exist in both the org and locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order is as follows

1. If you do any config in the org, use `sfdx force:source:pull`
2. If you add a local file or change a file locally do `sfdx force:source:push`
3. If there is a conflict resolve it and do a force push using -f flag using `sfdx force:source:push -f` to overwrite the org and overwrite the local files use `sfdx force:source:pull -f`

In case you do not want a file to be source tracked use .forceignore [file](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_exclude_source.htm)

**Update**

Use git or any other version control tool and keep synching your source often! That way you don't loose anything at all.

Comment: Thanks Mohith, but I am aware what `pull` and `push` do independently, I am more concerned about what I should do when I have changes both remotely and locally. Because earlier today when I had this exact same situation, I did `pull` and then `source:status` lost track of my local changes, so I could no longer do `push`

Comment: The pull should not have overridden local changes if there are changes you did locally and instead should have shown conflicts, should not have affected local added files. If you reproduce file a bug with repro steps.

Comment: In the end, I did a `push` and then `pull` and it worked fine...

Comment: pull should not override the files locally if conflict and should not wipe newly created files! If you reproduce open a bug

Comment: If it happens again, I will. It's made me feel a little nervous about using the `sfdx cli` which is slowing me down...

Comment: If I lose local tracking on changed files, is there a command I can run to prompt `sfdx` to find the local changes again?

Comment: I also recommend use a version control that way you can easily version and you won't loose anything in case something goes wrong

Comment: That is next on my list... :-)